# JDBC Question Mark in SQL Syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm n00b at Java and these are my first steps (4 days about 12 hours/day... <3 Java ;) ) with JDBC. Gotta problem with simple Query. 
I want to write a method witch return list of records with id greater than parameter. so wrote that:

```
    public List<Person> whereId(int id) {


        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id>?");

            while(resultSet.next()) {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                person.setfirstName(resultSet.getString("firstName"));
                person.setlastName(resultSet.getString("lastName"));

                persons.add(person);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(resultSet!= null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(statement!=null) {
                try {
                    statement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if(connection!=null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return persons;
   }
}
```

console is telling me that I have a wrong syntax in my manual that corresponds with my MariaDB. I wrote few methods in the same class but with only this I have a problem. If you know how to solve it please tell me. Maybe it's simple problem but I can't notice that. I was looking the answer on this site but I didn't find the answer ;(

Greetings :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you are executing the query using `Statement` but `Statement` won't support placeholders(?). However, `Prepared Statement` supports the placeholders.

Use

```
PreparedStatement preparedstatement= connection.PreaparedStatement("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id > ?");
```

For DQL quires `executeQuery()` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing...

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT FROM person WHERE id>?");
```

with

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person WHERE id > ?");
statement.setInt(1, minId);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

You'll need to set `minId` too.

Comment: it works! thanks a lot! I don't know why but I'll try to figure it out toomorrow :) Thank you once again! I tried to do that because i saw this in the other asked question on this site but that time I didn't change the Statement statement = null, to PreparedStatement statement... now it works :)

Comment: You use a prepared statement when you want to execute the same query more than once with different parameter values. If the expression `id > ?` will never change, you should just hardcode it like `id > 10` and then you don't need a prepared statement. If it will change, however, you should use the prepared statement as @Mike has shown.

Comment: @Matt - also when you want to prevent sql injection attacks.